# Null Pointer Exception in a get() method

Tags: arraylist, methods, nullpointerexception

I'm getting a null pointer exception in my getAddress() method and I don't know why. Here is the code including how I add elements into my array list.

```
public Address [] getAddresses() {
    Address [] rv = new Address [addressArray.size()];
   addressArray.toArray(rv);
   return rv;
}

public boolean addAddress(Address a) {
    if (a != null){
        return addressArray.add(a);
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean removeAddress(Address a) {
    if (a != null) {
    return addressArray.remove(a);
    }
    return false;
}
```

---

Anyone know why I'm getting this exception?

Comment: It would help if you post a stack trace for the null pointer exception, and the code where addressArray is defined.

Answer (score 0):

I would try null checking addressArray:

```
public Address[] getAddresses() {
  if (addressArray != null) {
    Address[] rv = new Address[addressArray.size()];
    addressArray.toArray(rv);
    return rv;
  }

  return new Address[0];
}
```